# Scraping Google Maps by Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have used Python, Selenium libraries and Google Chrome driver.
I searched for stores within my country the search results came up and everything is fine.
I have two problems first
1- The search repeats the results for the name of the store with the number of items shown in the search area
2- The search does not display all the results of the page and only shows a few of them that appear. It does not scroll to the bottom of the page to display all items on one page. After that, I want to go to another page
Until I reach the end of the search pages.

```
# Locating the results section
entries = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('widget-pane-content-holder')
# Prepare the excel file using the Openpyxl
path = r'E:\excel\companies.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet= wb.worksheets[0]
# Extracting the information from the results
for entry in entries:
    # Extracting the Name, address, Phone, and website
    name = entry.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]').text
   
    print(name)
       # Try/except  to write the extracted info in the Excel file pass if does.sn't exist
    try:
        sheet.append([name])
    except IndexError:
        pass
# saving the excel file
wb.save(path)
```

one in section result
[image]

'all section visible
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Iterate over listings with the following XPath query:

```
//div[contains(@aria-label, "Results for")]/div/div[./a]
```

Not just `/div/div/.../` but more advanced usage of contains, etc.

2. Try

```js
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);');
```

to scroll to the bottom of the page or

```js
driver
  .find_element_by_xpath(
    '//button[contains(@id, "section-pagination-button-next") and not(@disabled="true")]'
  )
  .click();
```

to navigate to the next page component. Be aware that with time the XPath might be different (so covering with tests will be nice practice).